# How may I create a dynamic message box/ progress bar with access 97?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Well, I do hate asking vague questions but I can't help it this time:
Some macros I'm coding are taking a long time to run - and I just realized that it's incredible boring to just wait for it.

I want a progress bar. Or even a message box stating "Loading..." with a cancel button.
I tried using MS help to do this, but they require an ActiveX controller and that's just not an option.

Personally, I really didn't even try to code anything becouse I'm not even sure if it's possible! Everytime I open a MsgBox the whole program stops running, and that's not my idea.

I tried checking some concepts in C+ or Java, but most people seem to use a function just for that.

Anyway, any kind of lead or small piece of information would help a lot.

PS.: Yeah, I'm using Access 97, and that's not something I can change in the moment.

Comment: Similar question (and suggestions) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238151/progress-bar-in-access-adp-2007

Comment: The example at [http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/displaying_a_progress_indicator/](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/displaying_a_progress_indicator/) doesn't seem to work on my machine - some modules were not found and excel keeps giving me an error "cannot access registry files".
While the example at [http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/progressbar.htm](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/progressbar.htm) doesn't seem to run at all. 
There's actually very little that I could use from those snippets, but I still have no idea how to display a message box while the code continues to run.

Comment: There's lots of sample code to be found via google - if you're having problems implementing one of those approaches, then it would help if you posted some code. Also, you mention Access in your question, but Excel in your last comment. Which are you using?

Comment: I believe that my current knowledge with VBA is not sufficient to express the problems I'm having. I'll be getting into some research before sending further info. 

Should I close this question or 'put it on hold'?

Comment: Or maybe here's a better question :

While a code is beeing executed, what are my options to warn the user that some is actually happening?
I'm thinking maybe a status box where the code would send information about what's beeing done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The problem with using MsgBox is that it stops everything until it gets a user response.  That's not what you need for this.
2. Try making a very simple Wait form.  It would have 1 unbounded label that says "Please Wait".  Before your calculations begin, call it up with a `docmd.OpenForm(...` and close it when you're done with a `docmd.closeform(...`

Comment: the command
DoCmd.OpenForm ("wait") 
worked fine. 
problem is 
DoCmd.closeform ("wait") didn't work at all... 
=(